# Selecting wifi router for better range

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I've a [TP Link TL-WR841N](http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR841N.html) 300 Mbps wifi router and I've issues with it's range.

It works perfectly if I connect from the same room, but over a standard brick wall, even from 3 m distance the connection sometimes gets slow, laggy and even drops. (Both from a HP EliteBook 840 G3 Windows 7, and also Samsung Smartphones with android).

I bought the router 5 years ago and it started to loose performance a few months ago. (maybe it's getting old? and there were also changes (change of ISP, modem, pc ...) which might cause compatibility issues too.)

So I've decided I'll replace it and now I'm asking for advice here for the selection.
What I've decided already is that I'll buy one with 802.11ac standard.
My issue is the range, I've been told routers having external antennas are generally better for this, but is there any other parameter I could check (reception sensitivity, transmit power ...) which affect it?

Note: *I'm not asking for selecting a specific hardware, I'm asking for help to understand routers.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wi-Fi access points do indeed die over time though I've not seen any analysis of why. I've always assumed that they are on 24x7 and output a fair bit of power so the electronics don't last more than a few years typically.

This is why I never recommend buying a router with built-in Wi-Fi any more. If you want good Wi-Fi, you end up buying an expensive router that you then have to replace though the router part is perfectly OK. I've had this happen a couple of times over the years. Maybe 30%-50% of the routers I've owned.

Regarding external aerials, it is true that they can indeed be better. However, it is the total design that has the biggest impact, especially in cheaper devices. I now use an Access Point that has no external aerials but has the best coverage of any AP or router I've ever owned. It is designed like the pro-level CISCO AP's but doesn't have the price tag. So I brought a non-Wi-Fi router and a separate AP for about the same price as a good consumer Wi-Fi router but it has far better control and far better performance.

And as you *didn't* ask, I will tell you that the devices are from Ubiquity. an [EdgeRouter Lite](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00EWYPA6Y) and [Unify UAP-LR AP](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ubiquiti-Networks-UAP-LR-Range-Router/dp/B00HXT8S9G).

Don't just take my word for it: [Review: Ubiquiti UniFi made me realise how terrible consumer Wi-Fi gear is](https://arstechnica.co.uk/gadgets/2016/05/ubiquiti-unifi-review-pro-wi-fi-router/)